# Python multiprocessing on mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm trying to insert to update really big values of data in a MySQL db and in the same try, I was trying to see in the process list what is doing!

So I made the following script:

I have a modified db MySQL that takes care to connect. Everything is working fine unless I use multiprocesses, if I use multiprocessing I got an error at some time with "Lost connection to database".

The script is like:

```
from mysql import DB
import multiprocessing

def check writing(db):
    result = db.execute("show full processlist").fethcall()
    for i in result:
        if i['State'] == "updating":
            print i['Info']

def main(db):
    # some work to create a big list of tuple called tuple
    sql = "update `table_name` set `field` = %s where `primary_key_id` = %s"
    
    monitor = multiprocessing.Process(target=check_writing,args=(db,)) # I create the monitor process
    monitor.start()
    db.execute_many(sql,tuple) # I start to modify table
    monitor.terminate()
    monitor.join

if __name__ == "__main__"
    
   db = DB(host,user,password,database_name) # this way I create the object connected

   main(db)

db.close()
```

And the a part of my mysql class is:

```
class DB:
   def __init__(self,host,user,password,db_name)
       self.db = MySQLdb.connect(host=host.... etc

def execute_many(self,sql,data):
    c = self.db.cursor()
    c.executemany(sql, data)
    c.close()
    self.db.commit()
```

As I said before, if I don't try to execute in `check_writing`, the script is working fine!

Maybe someone can explain me what is the cause and how can overcome? Also, I have problems trying to `threadPool` writing in MySQL using map (or `map_async`).
Do I miss something related to `mysql`?

Comment: After some researching with the module I have: MySQLdb. It seems that it doesn't offer any kind multithreading :(. http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to approach that:

**Connector/Python Connection Pooling**:

- mysql.connector.pooling module implements pooling.
- A pool opens a number of connections and handles thread safety when providing connections to requesters.
- The size of a connection pool is configurable at pool creation time. It cannot be resized thereafter.
- it is possible to have multiple connection pools. This enables applications to support pools of connections to different MySQL servers, for example.

[Check documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html)

I think your parallel processes are exhausting your mysql connections.

Comment: I've tried to follow the documentation and used: `self.db = MySQLdb.connect(pool_name = "mypool", pool_size = 3, host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, db=db_name, port=port, cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor, charset='utf8', init_command='SET NAMES UTF8')`.   But I receive this: `TypeError: 'pool_name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`. Did I miss something?